# Shortest focus distance of OV2640 camera modules with fixed focus

Tags: camera

Is it possible to decrease focus distance to 3-4 centimeters on fixed-focus OV2640 camera modules which sell with Chinese ESP-32 CAM or M5Stack ESP32 CAM?

They are set up to infinite focus out of the box.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Transistor, it's hard to find specs on camera module. There is datasheets for CMOS sensor https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/File:Ov2640_ds_1.8_.pdf but not lens. I think only one way - check it manually if you have one

Comment: Add approx. +25 - 30 dioptre lens

Comment: @NMF, 30 diopters is ~8x I think?

Comment: @br. Magnification is relative and depends on the rest of the optics, but for a hand magnifier, yes, 30D would be of the order of 8x magnification

Answer (score 2):

The existing lens is adjustable, you just need to turn the knurled ring around the lens, as shown here:

[image: diagram]

See whether that lets you focus close enough. If not, you might be able to find a different lens in the same kind of holder.

Comment: Yes, I know that it can be screwed up and down, but what mininum distantion without external lens?

Comment: I don't know. What did you get when you tried it?

Comment: I have no module in hands. I want to buy one but can't find such information. Hope that some DIYers have this.

Answer (score 2):

I tried it on the OV2640 camera that came with my ESP32-CAM. It has some kind of glue on it that makes it very hard to turn! I have read that you can take a VERY sharp small blade and cut through the translucent glue that are locking the threads and then be able to focus it manually.

But I do not know what the closest possible distance is however. But the closer the object is to the lens, the further away the CMOS sensor has to be. So if there is not enough threads on the lens holder, you could create an extension, somehow, that would enable focusing on closer objects.

BTW, you can also completely unscrew the lens and you should then be able to remove the IR filter so you can do "night vision" with IR LEDs for illumination.