# ESP32-cam or another camera for shooting at short distances

Tags: camera, esp32

I am trying to automate my mechanical water meters. It looks like this:

[image]

They are in a place that is difficult to get to, so I thought to place cameras, but distance between the meters and the wall is about 5-7 centimeters (2-2.5 inch). So, camera should be located at this distance in front of meter.

I tried to make a picture with an ESP32-cam with 1600x1200 resolution, placed camera in front of the counter/meter, but I see only circle on photo, the photo is completely blurred, unreadable. It's because of short distance between the camera and the meter.

I also tried to make a photo with my smartphone with 24MP camera, in the same distance. The smartphone blurred photo too, if to don't use it's focus. With manually focused (by tapping on the smartphone screen) camera it's blurred too, but more readable.

So, the question is:

Is it possible to make photos at short distances with ESP32-cam or should I use some other camera for it?
The solution can't be more expensive than $15-20 for each camera, because it's only for hobby, not a commercial project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shortenest focus distance of ov2640 camera modules with fixed focus](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/458332/shortenest-focus-distance-of-ov2640-camera-modules-with-fixed-focus)

Comment: At that distance you need a camera (or, more precisely, a lens) which is able to do macro photography. Apparently many of the IoT cameras actually have interchangeable lenses (with defaults focusing to infinity), so it’s probably a matter if finding the right lens and the right focus.

Answer (score 2):

Put a mirror on the wall, put the camera on top of the water meter or even further away and flip the image in software at the receiving PC.

Comment: Nice lateral thinking! +1